# Why is this break; fixing my issue when it seems to change nothing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to code an equipment manager for a game.

Here is the code:

```
public class EquipmentManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int slots;
    public List<Equipment> defaultEquipment;
    public List<Equipment> currentEquipment;

    private void Start()
    {
        slots = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(EquipmentSlot)).Length;

        EquipDefault();
    }

    public void Equip(Equipment newEquipment)
    {
        foreach (Equipment oldEquipment in currentEquipment)
        {
            if (oldEquipment.slot == newEquipment.slot)
            {
                Unequip(oldEquipment);
                break;
            }
        }

        currentEquipment.Add(newEquipment);
        gameObject.GetComponent<AvatarManager>().RenderPrefab(newEquipment.prefabName, true);
    }

    public void Unequip(Equipment oldEquipment)
    {
        currentEquipment.Remove(oldEquipment);
        gameObject.GetComponent<AvatarManager>().RenderPrefab(oldEquipment.prefabName, false);
    }

    public void EquipDefault()
    {
        foreach (Equipment equipment in defaultEquipment)
        {
            Equip(equipment);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `break;` from the `if` inside the `foreach` loop the new equipment doesn't get added to `currentEquipment` and I also get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Why???? It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection whilst you are iterating over it using a `foreach` loop. With the `break` statement, the loop is never reaching the next iteration after you modify it with `UnEquip()`, and thus it doesn't error.

To have the same functionality, you could iterate over the collection using a normal `for` loop, and use `currentEquipment.RemoveAt(i)` to remove it from the List.

Comment: He don't need to use a loop at all.

Comment: He doesn't, but I'm just telling him how to fix his code, not to push him a different direction.

Comment: Another option is to use `ToList()` in the `foreach`, I.E: `foreach (Equipment oldEquipment in currentEquipment.ToList()`, though `for` is certainly more memory efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop here if you are equipping one item at a time.

```
    public static void Equip(Equipment newEquipment)
    {
        var equippedItem = currentEquipment.FirstOrDefault(oldEquipment => oldEquipment.slot == newEquipment.slot);

        if (equippedItem != null)
            Unequip(equippedItem);

        currentEquipment.Add(newEquipment);
        gameObject.GetComponent<AvatarManager>().RenderPrefab(newEquipment.prefabName, true);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but it was helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: If introducing a user into linq you should at least add a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) and explain slightly how Linq enumerations work in general since this also has a lot of possible pitfalls if you're not knowing what you are using there.

Comment: Is `Find` better than `FirstOrDefault` in this case?

Comment: @kejodion `Find` certainly would have a bit more of a performance gain as `Find` uses a `for` loop to enumerate the collection, whereas `First` uses `foreach`.